# Android XML background circle in corners

Tags: android, xml

I want to define a backgound image using XML. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item >
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#C0C0C0" />
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:right="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="3dp">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

For some visual reasons, I want to draw circles in each corner of this background with XML.

Is there a possibility to do so? For example like this:

[image: Expected output]

Comment: post your expected output

Comment: edited question

Comment: @Billabong did you find a solution for this? If yes, do share.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RoundedImageView` class, 
 
`compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'` 
Look at this link
[RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView)